# app crashes immediately without giving any information in the debug

Tags: c#, api, xamarin, xamarin.forms, crash

I am trying to run a Search Function in APP, and it crashes immediately without giving any information.

**My MVVM Code**

```
var userSearch = _apiServices.SearchEmailansPasswordUserAsync(Email,Password,accesstoken);
```

---

**My Data Services**

```
public async Task<data.UserT> SearchEmailansPasswordUserAsync(string email, string pasword, string accessToken)
{
    RestClient<data.UserT> restClient = new RestClient<data.UserT>();
    var userInformation = await restClient.SearchEmailandPasswordUser(email, pasword, accessToken);
    return userInformation;
}
```

**My REST Client Code**

```
public async Task<T> SearchEmailandPasswordUser(string email, string pasword, string accessToken)
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);                    
    var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(publicUrl + "api/UserCredentials/email=" + email + "/pasword=" + pasword);//code crashes her 
    var taskModels = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
    return taskModels;                                                   
}
```

**My User Controller in API**

```
[HttpGet]        
[Route("api/UserCredentials/email={email}/pasword={pasword}")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SearchUseremail(string email ,string pasword)
{
    UserT login = await db.UserTs.Where(x => x.Email == email && x.Password == pasword).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
    if (login == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return Ok(login);
}
```

The line of code that crashes is the following:

```
var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(publicUrl + "api/UserCredentials/email=" + email + "/pasword=" + pasword);//code crashes her
```

Comment: It looks like it's a native exception, and that's why you see no errors. Have you tried using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` and `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` to catch the exception ?

Comment: Have you looked in Windows Event Viewer (usually underneath Windows Logs -> Application)?

Comment: Did you check the output log? sometimes the native error are mentioned in log. What platform is it crashing in?

Comment: kaj no i have not tried that code ..

Comment: @ansbedoor Please remember to check you have set the internet  permission firstly, if you still have this issue, I suggest you can take a look:https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/4380